# Is it possible to programmatically remove restart markers from JPEG images?

Tags: c++, linux, image-processing, libjpeg

Is it possible to programmatically remove restart markers from JPEG images?

Answer (score 3):

[jpegtran](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=jpegtran) can add markers with `-restart N` so it can probably also remove them.  Even if it can't, it's the right tool to modify if you want to write that feature yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It is a simple matter of writing a byte-stream copier that understands the JPEG stream file format, and in response to finding an RSTn marker, omitting it on output.  Additionally, the JPEG header needs to be altered so that the DRI (define restart interval) marker is removed.

The restart markers are used solely for mid-stream resumption of decoding, such as when corruption of the file has been found.  Without RSTn markers, it would be difficult to recompose MOST of an image from a slight missing chunk of data.